# Attempting to debug Xamarin Forms app results in instantly closing app on physical device and "failed to connect to socket error"

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to run my Xamarin Forms app for Android with a debugger through Visual Studio.  When I look in the android logs, I notice the following error multiple times:

`10-14 03:43:56.384 25643 25643 E adbd    : failed to connect to socket 'tcp:8857': Connection refused`

Otherwise, the app will close immediately after being started, without ever even running any of the code.  Attempting to run the app in the emulator with the debugger results in no problems.

Comment: Do you have minimal code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the following reasons:

1. The server Ip or port of the client socket connection is wrong, make sure your debugging environment is in the same local area network.
2. Android's network requests cannot be made on the main thread.
3. There's no firewall blocking the connection.